# Determine the fixed field of complex conjugation on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-numbers, field-theory, galois-theory

Determine the  fixed field of complex conjugation of $\mathbb{C}$

---

**My attempt** :There is a theorem in Galois theory: let  $E/F $ be a finite Galois extension with Galois group $G=\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)$. Then the fixed  field of $G$ is $F$

Now take $E= \mathbb{C}$ and  $F= \mathbb{R}$ then the fixed  field of $G$ is $\mathbb{R}$

Therefore, the fixed field of complex conjugation on $\mathbb{C}$ is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: That is correct. In fact, since there are no algebraic fields between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ it can only by $\mathbb R$. Note that you can solve this with much less theory:
$a+\mathrm i b = a -\mathrm i b$ iff $b=0$. Done.

Comment: This is however slightly cheating, as you used the result that $\Bbb C/\Bbb R$ is a finite Galois extension whose Galois group is generated by the complex conjugation. A direct proof of your statement is much simpler and might be unavoidable in the proof of the above result. Usually this kind of exercises asks you to work out an example without using the theory.

Comment: Your solution did not use "complex conjugation" at all.  The theorem you cite would say: if you take *all* the automorphisms of $\mathbb C$ that fix $\mathbb R$, the a point fixed by all of them belongs to $\mathbb R$.  So to get the fixed field of complex conjugation, you need to show complex conjugation is the only automorphism (except the identity) of $\mathbb C$ that fixes $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a simpler approach. Consider $\overline{\,.\,}\colon\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$ as a field homomorphism. Now, we know that every $z\in\mathbb C$ is of the form $z=a+bi$ with $\overline{a+bi}=a-bi$, $a,b\in\mathbb R$. Being fixed now means that

$$
a+bi=a-bi\,\iff\,2bi=0\,\iff\,b=0\,.
$$

Hence the *set* of fixed points of complex conjugation is $\mathbb R$, which is also a field and hence the fixed field of complex conjugation.